Is there any way to match exactly one character?
I have a directory containing the files file.txt, file1.txt, and file2.txt.  I'm trying to write a batch file that processes the last two only.  However, when I say for %%f in (file*.txt), it matches all 3.  Same for file?.txt, which is a bit surprising given that a ? wildcard is specifically supposed to represent a single character.
What's the right way to write this, so I will only get files that begin with file plus something after it, plus .txt on the end?

? means 0 or 1 character and not a single character. * means 0 or more characters. There could be used also for /F %%I in ('dir file?.txt /A-D-L /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /X "file[0123456789]\.txt"') do echo %%I for searching for just files (not directories and links) matching file?.txt with ? matching an ASCII digit verified with findstr which filters out all other file names.

@Mofi, just be aware that the question asks to match "file plus something after it". Something is not necessarily a digit in that case, despite the 1 and 2 examples provided at the top of the question.

Right, @Compo There can be used also for /F %%I in ('dir file?.txt /A-D-L /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /X "file.\.txt"') do echo %%I to match file plus any single character after it plus .txt.

Well, better would be for /F "tokens=*" %%I in ('dir file?.txt /A-D-L /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /X "file.\.txt"') do echo %%I or for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir file?.txt /A-D-L /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /X "file.\.txt"') do echo %%I or for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%I in ('dir file?.txt /A-D-L /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /X "file.\.txt"') do echo %%I for working also for the file with name file .txt with a space character after file and before .txt.

There are ways you could achieve it by using a built-in utility which actually does use ? to represent exactly one character, where.exe.
You can use that with a for /f loop to isolate exactly what you want:
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Set "PathExt=" ^& %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe ".":"file?.txt"') Do Echo %%~nxG

EndLocal

In the above script I have used a relative . for the current directory, as implied by your own command example.
Using where.exe has the added benefits of matching all files, (including hidden and system), outputting the full path, (in the above case %%G), and matching exactly the extension .txt, (for instance Dir *.doc, and For %G In (*.doc) Do Echo %G will generally match .docx files too, due to matching the 8.3 naming pattern).
